# Oracle SQL Collapse Data Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

The queried data is currently returned as follows:

```
UserName        Op1        Op2        Op3
--------        ---        ---        ---
 User1           1          0          0
 User2           1          1          1
 User3           1          1          0
```

The results should just be a single row:

```
Ops1                    Ops2               Ops3
----                    ----               ----
User1, User2, User3     User2, User3       User2
```

How can I do that in Oracle?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please edit the tags.

Comment: This is a really weird way of storing and presenting your data. Please normalize your schema...

Comment: I don't have control over the schema.

Comment: Alright, that is understandable. Still, it would be nice to advise someone on doing so :)

Comment: What determines the order in which the strings are aggregated together? Why `'User2, User3'` and not `'User3, User2'`? Is it in alphabetical order of the strings themselves?

Comment: The order makes no difference.

Comment: Then in the `LISTAGG()` function it will be more efficient to write `within group (order by NULL)` - saving the (potentially long) time to arrange the tokens alphabetically. "Order by NULL" means don't order at all, take them in whatever order they are found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way - using `LISTAGG()` (which, I believe, requires Oracle version 11.2 or higher):

```
with
  test_data ( username, op1, op2, op3 ) as (
    select 'User1', 1, 0, 0 from dual union all
    select 'User2', 1, 1, 1 from dual union all
    select 'User3', 1, 1, 0 from dual
  )
select listagg(case op1 when 1 then username end, ',') 
                               within group (order by username) as ops1,
       listagg(case op2 when 1 then username end, ',') 
                               within group (order by username) as ops2,
       listagg(case op3 when 1 then username end, ',')
                              within group (order by username) as ops3
from   test_data
;

OPS1               OPS2               OPS3              
------------------ ------------------ ------------------
User1,User2,User3  User2,User3        User2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DECODE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) to output the username if the number is 1, the empty word otherwise. Concatenate the names with [`LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DECODE(OP1, 1, USERNAME, ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USERNAME) OPS1,
       LISTAGG(DECODE(OP2, 1, USERNAME, ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USERNAME) OPS2,
       LISTAGG(DECODE(OP3, 1, USERNAME, ''), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USERNAME) OPS3
       FROM ELBAT;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bcce05c6df58378b8729bd0bfac995af)

Comment: Thanks.  I think this will work too, but I like the answer by MathGuy.